# How to block mouseleave animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, slideup

I'm currently struggling with a huge problem. I have a mouseleave animation set, but I need to block it, and what is the most interesting here, I don't have access to the code where this animation is set.

This unreachable for me code is here:

```
.on('mouseleave', function(e) {
                if(!$(e.relatedTarget).parent().is(el)) {
                    el.stop(true, true).slideUp('fast');
                }
            });
```

Basically I need to delete this animation, I don't want it to happen.

What I tried already:

```
$(this).stop().clearQueue().finish().off('mouseleave');
```

None of that works for me.

Halp!

Comment: Are you gonna replace the code with another animation? If not you could use `$(myElement).unbind('mouseleave');`

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements." - http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: I just needed to stop it, not replace it with something different.
So yeah, `el.unbind('mouseleave');` worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, we have an answer.

```
$('foo').unbind('mouseleave');
```

aswell as

```
$('foo').unbind();
```

worked perfectly.